# Ionic Failed to capture fingerprint of input files for task ':app:preDebugBuild' property 'compileManifests' during up-to-date check

Tags: android, firebase, ionic-framework, build

Okey, so I'm working on an ionic app for android and this week I updated the plugins, cordova and ionic and it won't build the apk any more. I know the problem is with the firebase pluguin, but I don't know how to fix it.

I created a new ionic project, installed cordova latest version and builded the apk, it works.
I added the firebase plugin (ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase + npm install @ionic-native/firebase) and tried to build the apk, but I get the following error:

```
BUILD FAILED in 1s
C:\Users\jmir\goInstall\platforms\android\gradlew: Command failed with         
exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Failed to capture fingerprint of input files for task ':app:preDebugBuild' property 'compileManifests' during up-to-date check.
> The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base is being requested by various other libraries at [[17.0.0,17.0.0], [17.2.0,17.2.0]], but resolves to 17.2.0. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

    cordova.cmd build android exited with exit code 1.

    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

I can't show you some code, because I really didn't changed anything, just added the plugin I need.

I've tried with old versions of ionic, cordova and firebase, still get the same error.

Comment: what other plugins are u also using?

Comment: I'm using just fire and firebase, in this case

Comment: I guess it's not a plugin, but I ran npm install firebase @angular/fire --save in my project

Answer (score 2):

Ionic Failed to capture fingerprint of input files for task ':app:preDebugBuild' property 'compileManifests' during up-to-date check
This problems occurs is because of fcm so 
1).first remove platform

ionic cordova platform rm android

2).Remove fcm

cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-firebase-lib

3).Add Platform

ionic cordova platform add android@latest

4).Add fcm 
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated 
npm install @ionic-native/fcm

5)ionic cordova build android

Comment: Please show the error then i will suggest you.. And show the data of ionic info.. Means platform and cli details

Comment: i am  not using  cordova-plugin-firebase-lib plugin?

Comment: Then try with reomve and add platform